# Calculate Weighted Average Based on Games Played

Tags: math, statistics, weighted-average

I'm trying to rank our players based on their average position they finished and weighted by the number of games they've played in based on the total number of games run.

Given the following set of numbers. I'm calculating the weighted average like this

**Average Place(played/games) = Weighted Average**

The reason behind this is to change the players ranking based on the overall number of games played. For example, I don't want someone who played one game and came in 1st to have a top ranking. I would think that a player who played maybe 200 games and averaged 3rd place would rank higher.

Given the data below, I would expect Player 4 to rank higher than Player 5, but that's not how it's coming out.

Am I thinking of this correctly?

```
Total games 1179

Player 1
Number of games played 24
Average place finished 11
Weighted Average 0.223919


Player 2  
Number of games played 274
Average place finished 18
Weighted Average 4.183206

Player 3
Number of games played 107
Average place finished 13
Weighted Average 1.179813

Player 4
Number of games played 188
Average place finished 6
Weighted Average 0.956743003

Player 5
Number of games played 81
Average place finished 15
Weighted Average 1.030534
```

Comment: You need to change your weighted average formula. I assume you want a higher (rather than lower) weighted average to correspond to better playing, but your weighted average increases as `Average Place` increases. This means that if players A and B play the same number of games, and A always gets 1st place and B always gets 100th place, player B will have a weighted average 100 times that of player A. Note that your formula does increase as `played/games`, which is what you want. So you could use something like `weighted average = (played / games) / (average place)`

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: This worked out perfectly!